# How can I edit existing mysql tables with directus cms?

Tags: mysql, directus

How can I edit existing mysql tables with directus cms?
Do I have to create a table in directus manually in the exact way as the existing one or is there a possibility to use/import the existing one?

Regards 
ms

Answer (score 6):

If you install a fresh Directus instance, then you can just import your existing SQL tables/content into that database... then under `Settings > Collections & Fields` you'll see a button for each imported table that says "Manage". That should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible later to import new tables?
How do I import a existing table?

Comment: Yeah! You can do it at any point... just import them right into the database and they will show up in Settings with that "Manage" button. Directus is kind of like a database administration tool in that way.

Comment: Thanks, perfect :)

Comment: Awesome. Don't forget to mark this as the solution if it works for you!

Comment: Did anything change in more recent versions of Directus such that this no longer works? I'm using 9.21.2, connecting to an existing DB, see that it populated the directus schema with its system tables, but it doesn't show any of my other schema or tables. I've poked around all UI buttons, and can confirm the DB user has permissions to see the other schema/tables. Thanks.